# sliding window with electric roller shutter doesn't fully close

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, blinds

I have this window which doesn't fully close. It stucks at some point while closing. I can hear its electric motor still working but something prevents it from fully closing. So half of the holes are visible:
[image]

I've cleaned the window very well and even applied WD-40 on its rails but nothing changed.

Any idea on where should I look at next?

Comment: Do you have a make and model for the electric motor? Does it come in a kit?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. I'll try to open the case at the top and see what it is. I think the motor is fine though.